# Second Monitor doesn't work properly (Ubuntu 14.04, Dell XPS13 Dev. Edition (Intel HD4000))

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell

I fail at configuring a second monitor using Mini-Display-Port > HDMI cable > ASUS MX279 on Ubuntu 14.04, Dell XPS 13 Dev. Edition (latest Intel HD4000 drivers installed). Out of the box it worked first, then signal disappeared. I rebooted, signal disappeared again and did not reappear. (Also connection to monitor is no longer established).

Then I followed these instructions: [Can I force VGA signal output even when xrandr shows 'disconnected'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150879/can-i-force-vga-signal-output-even-when-xrandr-shows-disconnected)

It did not work (cannot configure CRC1). I changed HDMI cable to pricier one, no success. I searched 3 hours for solutions and did not find a particular one to be used for a newbie like me... any ideas?

Comment: Can you run: sudo xrandr -q post the output. If this has been solved already, post your solution and mark.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest switching mini dp adapter.

I originally tried using an Apple Brand mini dp to vga adapter without success. I bought a [StarTech (mini dp to 1 HDMI)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00310EEO4) and it solved my problem.

I've also used the [StarTech mini dp to multi (VGA/HDMI/DVI)](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=8898915&CatId=467) successfully.

Comment: The dell adapter works well for me.

Comment: Do have a model or link? Been testing a lot of the mini displayport adapters to multiple monitors, but I haven't figured it out just yet.

Comment: Here is the one I'm using: http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=332-2271 It is also available on Amazon.