# Native resolution not supported

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

```
DP-1 connected primary 1440x900+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1440x900      59.89*+
   1920x1080     60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94
```

This is the output I get from `xrandr -q`

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c82 (rev a1)
```

All of the resolutions work (are bad looking though), but the only one that doesn't work (the one I want) does not. All I get is `No signal` from my monitor when I do this:

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 1440x900
```

Additional info:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-370                                 370.28-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2                    amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 370.28
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-370                      370.28-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2                    amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.2                                         amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            370.28-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                    amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Model: Samsung LE19R86BD

```
$ cvt 1440 900
# 1440x900 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.30MA) hsync: 55.93 kHz; pclk: 106.50 MHz
Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "1440x900_59.89"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode DP-1 "1440x900_59.89"  
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  37
  Current serial number in output stream:  38
```

Comment: @ElderGeek not sure what you mean. That is the output it gives me. My monitor doesn't have the option to change it to 59.89.

Comment: I see that. The question is whether it's accurate for your monitor. Make and model might be useful.

Comment: @ElderGeek not really. My resolution IS listed. Besides, I get BadMatch error everytime I try to add a mode.

Comment: What's the actual FULL output for `xrandr -q` ? You cut off the outputs

Answer (score 0):

Try `xrandr --newmode 900p  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync`

or

`xrandr --addmode 900p  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync`

Also related: [Can I force VGA signal output even when xrandr shows 'disconnected'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150879/can-i-force-vga-signal-output-even-when-xrandr-shows-disconnected)

According to the [Specifications](https://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-le19r86bd-19-lcd-tv/specs/) for your screen.

Supported Computer Resolutions
1024 x 768 (XGA), 1152 x 864, 1360 x 768, 640 x 350, 640 x 480 (VGA), 720 x 400, 800 x 600 (SVGA)

You might find 1360x768 gives better results. (that's the resolution I use when using my TV as a monitor)

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851704/xrandr-errors-badname-named-color-or-font-does-not-exist

Comment: Doesn't let me switch to it.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: But why does it still give me BadMatch? I can't add a new mode.

Comment: It appears that there is an [incompatibility](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324211) between xrandr and the Nvidia driver

Comment: I managed to add it through the NVIDIA X Server and still no signal :-(