# HDMI not detected on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi, xrandr

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 from version 16.04, the external monitor is not detected anymore. I have tried using both VGA and HDMI monitor ports to connect using the USB-C adapter to my laptop. Also, I have tried with two different monitors and two USB-C adapters.

Specs:

- Dell XPS 9370
- Ubuntu 18.04.1
- Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
- kernel 4.18.0-15-generic

What I've tried:

- Reinstall and use lightdm instead of gdm3 as explained here: [External monitor not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- Force VGA output when it shows disconnected as explained here: [Can I force VGA signal output even when xrandr shows 'disconnected'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150879/can-i-force-vga-signal-output-even-when-xrandr-shows-disconnected)

xrander output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93    48.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Output from `xrandr --verbose`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x48) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  4109678
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004d10841400000000
        281b0104a51d11780ede50a3544c9926
        0f505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101ac3780a070383e403020
        350026a510000018892c80a070383e40
        3020350026a510000018000000fe0057
        54315233814c513133334d3100000000
        0002410328001200000b010a20200001
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
  1920x1080 (0x48) 142.520MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  68.52KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1142           clock  60.00Hz
  1920x1080 (0x49) 266.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1920 start 1944 end 1960 total 2000 skew    0 clock 133.25KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1081 end 1084 total 1111           clock  59.97Hz
  1920x1080 (0x4a) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
  1920x1080 (0x4b) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1920x1080 (0x4c) 114.010MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  54.81KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1142           clock  48.00Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4d) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1680x1050 (0x4e) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1600x1024 (0x4f) 103.125MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1600 end 1656 total 1664 skew    0 clock  61.97KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1024 end 1029 total 1030           clock  60.17Hz
  1400x1050 (0x50) 122.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock  59.98Hz
  1600x900 (0x51) 246.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1600 start 1728 end 1900 total 2200 skew    0 clock 111.82KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  932           clock  59.99Hz
  1600x900 (0x52) 186.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1600 start 1624 end 1640 total 1680 skew    0 clock 111.01KHz
        v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  926           clock  59.94Hz
  1600x900 (0x53) 118.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934           clock  59.95Hz
  1600x900 (0x54) 97.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1648 end 1680 total 1760 skew    0 clock  55.40KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  926           clock  59.82Hz
  1280x1024 (0x55) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x56) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1400x900 (0x57) 103.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1480 end 1624 total 1848 skew    0 clock  56.01KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  934           clock  59.96Hz
  1400x900 (0x58) 86.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1448 end 1480 total 1560 skew    0 clock  55.45KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  913 total  926           clock  59.88Hz
  1280x960 (0x59) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x810 (0x5a) 198.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1440 start 1548 end 1704 total 1968 skew    0 clock 100.67KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  839           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x810 (0x5b) 151.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1440 start 1464 end 1480 total 1520 skew    0 clock  99.92KHz
        v: height  810 start  811 end  814 total  833           clock  59.97Hz
  1368x768 (0x5c) 85.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.88Hz
  1368x768 (0x5d) 72.250MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1368 start 1416 end 1448 total 1528 skew    0 clock  47.28KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.85Hz
  1360x768 (0x5e) 84.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.80Hz
  1360x768 (0x5f) 72.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.96Hz
  1280x800 (0x60) 174.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1380 end 1516 total 1752 skew    0 clock  99.46KHz
        v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  829           clock  59.99Hz
  1280x800 (0x61) 134.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  98.71KHz
        v: height  800 start  801 end  804 total  823           clock  59.97Hz
  1280x800 (0x62) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  1280x800 (0x63) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
  1152x864 (0x64) 81.620MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  895           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x65) 156.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1512 total 1744 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  746           clock  60.00Hz
  1280x720 (0x66) 120.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1280 start 1304 end 1320 total 1360 skew    0 clock  88.79KHz
        v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  740           clock  59.99Hz
  1280x720 (0x67) 74.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock  59.86Hz
  1280x720 (0x68) 63.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  44.27KHz
        v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  741           clock  59.74Hz
  1024x768 (0x69) 133.475MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1100 end 1212 total 1400 skew    0 clock  95.34KHz
        v: height  768 start  768 end  770 total  794           clock  60.04Hz
  1024x768 (0x6a) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  960x720 (0x6b) 117.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1128 total 1300 skew    0 clock  90.00KHz
        v: height  720 start  720 end  722 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
  928x696 (0x6c) 109.150MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   928 start  976 end 1088 total 1264 skew    0 clock  86.35KHz
        v: height  696 start  696 end  698 total  719           clock  60.05Hz
  896x672 (0x6d) 102.400MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   896 start  960 end 1060 total 1224 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
        v: height  672 start  672 end  674 total  697           clock  60.01Hz
  1024x576 (0x6e) 98.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1092 end 1200 total 1376 skew    0 clock  71.58KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  597           clock  59.95Hz
  1024x576 (0x6f) 78.375MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1064 total 1104 skew    0 clock  70.99KHz
        v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  592           clock  59.96Hz
  1024x576 (0x70) 46.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1160 total 1296 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  599           clock  59.90Hz
  1024x576 (0x71) 42.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1104 total 1184 skew    0 clock  35.47KHz
        v: height  576 start  579 end  584 total  593           clock  59.82Hz
  960x600 (0x72) 96.625MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1028 end 1128 total 1296 skew    0 clock  74.56KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  622           clock  59.93Hz
  960x600 (0x73) 77.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  60.00Hz
  960x540 (0x74) 86.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start 1024 end 1124 total 1288 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  560           clock  59.96Hz
  960x540 (0x75) 69.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  555           clock  59.99Hz
  960x540 (0x76) 40.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   960 start  992 end 1088 total 1216 skew    0 clock  33.51KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  562           clock  59.63Hz
  960x540 (0x77) 37.250MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   960 start 1008 end 1040 total 1120 skew    0 clock  33.26KHz
        v: height  540 start  543 end  548 total  556           clock  59.82Hz
  800x600 (0x78) 81.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x79) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x7a) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  840x525 (0x7b) 73.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  892 end  980 total 1120 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  544           clock  60.01Hz
  840x525 (0x7c) 59.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock  59.88Hz
  864x486 (0x7d) 32.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   864 start  888 end  968 total 1072 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  506           clock  59.92Hz
  864x486 (0x7e) 30.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   864 start  912 end  944 total 1024 skew    0 clock  29.79KHz
        v: height  486 start  489 end  494 total  500           clock  59.57Hz
  800x512 (0x7f) 51.562MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  800 end  828 total  832 skew    0 clock  61.97KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  515           clock  60.17Hz
  700x525 (0x80) 61.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock  59.98Hz
  800x450 (0x81) 59.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  848 end  928 total 1056 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.95Hz
  800x450 (0x82) 48.750MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  824 end  840 total  880 skew    0 clock  55.40KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  463           clock  59.82Hz
  640x512 (0x83) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  844 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height  512 start  512 end  514 total  533           clock  60.02Hz
  720x450 (0x84) 53.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   720 start  760 end  836 total  952 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.89Hz
  700x450 (0x85) 51.750MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  740 end  812 total  924 skew    0 clock  56.01KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  467           clock  59.96Hz
  700x450 (0x86) 43.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  724 end  740 total  780 skew    0 clock  55.45KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  456 total  463           clock  59.88Hz
  640x480 (0x87) 54.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  688 end  744 total  900 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  480 start  480 end  482 total  500           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x88) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  720x405 (0x89) 22.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  744 end  808 total  896 skew    0 clock  25.11KHz
        v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  422           clock  59.51Hz
  720x405 (0x8a) 21.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   720 start  768 end  800 total  880 skew    0 clock  24.72KHz
        v: height  405 start  408 end  413 total  419           clock  58.99Hz
  684x384 (0x8b) 42.625MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   684 start  720 end  788 total  892 skew    0 clock  47.79KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  399           clock  59.88Hz
  684x384 (0x8c) 36.125MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   684 start  708 end  724 total  764 skew    0 clock  47.28KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.85Hz
  680x384 (0x8d) 42.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   680 start  716 end  784 total  888 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  399           clock  59.80Hz
  680x384 (0x8e) 36.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   680 start  704 end  720 total  760 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.96Hz
  640x400 (0x8f) 41.750MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  676 end  740 total  840 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  415           clock  59.88Hz
  640x400 (0x90) 35.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  680 total  720 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
        v: height  400 start  401 end  404 total  411           clock  59.98Hz
  576x432 (0x91) 40.810MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   576 start  608 end  668 total  760 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
        v: height  432 start  432 end  434 total  447           clock  60.06Hz
  640x360 (0x92) 37.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  44.77KHz
        v: height  360 start  361 end  364 total  374           clock  59.86Hz
  640x360 (0x93) 31.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   640 start  664 end  680 total  720 skew    0 clock  44.27KHz
        v: height  360 start  361 end  364 total  370           clock  59.83Hz
  640x360 (0x94) 18.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  22.50KHz
        v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  376           clock  59.84Hz
  640x360 (0x95) 17.750MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  688 end  720 total  800 skew    0 clock  22.19KHz
        v: height  360 start  363 end  368 total  374           clock  59.32Hz
  512x384 (0x96) 32.500MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock  60.00Hz
  512x288 (0x97) 23.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  532 end  580 total  648 skew    0 clock  35.88KHz
        v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  299           clock  60.00Hz
  512x288 (0x98) 21.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  536 end  552 total  592 skew    0 clock  35.47KHz
        v: height  288 start  289 end  292 total  296           clock  59.92Hz
  480x270 (0x99) 20.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   480 start  496 end  544 total  608 skew    0 clock  33.51KHz
        v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  281           clock  59.63Hz
  480x270 (0x9a) 18.625MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   480 start  504 end  520 total  560 skew    0 clock  33.26KHz
        v: height  270 start  271 end  274 total  278           clock  59.82Hz
  400x300 (0x9b) 20.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  420 end  484 total  528 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  302 total  314           clock  60.32Hz
  400x300 (0x9c) 18.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  412 end  448 total  512 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  300 start  300 end  301 total  312           clock  56.34Hz
  432x243 (0x9d) 16.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   432 start  444 end  484 total  536 skew    0 clock  30.32KHz
        v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  253           clock  59.92Hz
  432x243 (0x9e) 15.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   432 start  456 end  472 total  512 skew    0 clock  29.79KHz
        v: height  243 start  244 end  247 total  250           clock  59.57Hz
  320x240 (0x9f) 12.587MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock  60.05Hz
  360x202 (0xa0) 11.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  372 end  404 total  448 skew    0 clock  25.11KHz
        v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  211           clock  59.51Hz
  360x202 (0xa1) 10.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   360 start  384 end  400 total  440 skew    0 clock  24.72KHz
        v: height  202 start  204 end  206 total  209           clock  59.13Hz
  320x180 (0xa2)  9.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  332 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  22.50KHz
        v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  188           clock  59.84Hz
  320x180 (0xa3)  8.875MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  344 end  360 total  400 skew    0 clock  22.19KHz
        v: height  180 start  181 end  184 total  187           clock  59.32Hz
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  4109678
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     HDMI-1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  4109678
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     DP-1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x45
    Timestamp:  4109678
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     HDMI-2
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x46
    Timestamp:  4109678
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     DP-2
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
```

Output from `lspci`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell UHD Graphics 620
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Memory at db000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 50000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Output from `uname -a`:

```
Linux xps 4.18.0-15-generic #16~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 14:06:04 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any recommendations? Could this be a hardware failure?

EDIT(s):

- Added the `xrandr --verbose` output
- More information about what I have tried

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto
sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1920x1080
sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0
```

Also you can use a GUI for xrandr:

```
sudo apt-get install arandr
```

Last try is to install latest nvidia drivers for the xserver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-410 nvidia-*
```

In your case upgrade the intel drivers:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade xserver-xorg-video-intel -y 

sudo reboot
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The output after running both commands is: `xrandr: cannot find mode 1920x1080`

Comment: I have added the mode

Comment: Keeps without working. Adding `--verbose` to the output command, it shows: 
`crtc 1:    1920x1080  60.00 +0+0 "HDMI-1"`

Comment: I have updated the answer to update the nvidia drivers

Comment: My laptop does not have an nvidia GPU. Do you think that I still need the nvidia drivers?

Comment: Yes try it out .. you can still remove it

Comment: @Alpy Installing Nvidia drivers makes no sense.

Comment: I literally woke up and ubuntu didn't connect to external anymore. Im getting this: xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed

Comment: I have tried so many things.  About a month ago, on Ubuntu 18.04, my external monitor stopped being recognized.  My laptop recognized my TV though.  Drivers were fine, deleting monitors.xml, nothing worked.  xrandr commands now allows my external monitor to work, but only in mirror mode and I cannot close my laptop lid.  Detect displays does not work still.  However, these are the only commands that have allowed me to at least use my external monitors.  If there is any input on additional steps I might try, that would be appreciated.

Comment: My problem was that monitor was detected after unplugged and plugged. Legion 15 on Kubuntu21.04  with nvidia and with nouveau driver. after running xrandr --verbose, it detected automatically

Comment: @Marc does it work for you?

Comment: Sorry for not updating the question with the result, but it was a hardware failure.