# HDMI not detected on AMD Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-graphics

Everything was working for months until on the day I ordered new keyboards and monitor I woke my **Dell inspiron15** up and external **HDMI monitor** was **not recognized** anymore. Can't make this stuff up.

- Checked monitor with different PC - WORKS
- Checked my PC HDMI port - WORKS *(monitor starts scanning procedure)*

First off, I have tried everything [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121132/hdmi-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04/1121139#1121139) but I'm getting he following:

```
sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto                     <-- OK
sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1920x1080                 <-- OK
sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 <--ERR: xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

I also tried to replace the 3rd command with this but same ERR:

```
sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of eDP-1
```

**Here is my setup**:

Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)

Output of `lshw -c video`

```
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: UHD Graphics 620
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:138 memory:d1000000-d1ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
*-display
   description: Display controller
   product: Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: c1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
   resources: irq:140 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0200000-d023ffff memory:d0240000-d025ffff
```

Output of `xrandr --verbose`

```
    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
    eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    47.10  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   ...
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) <-- ISSUE HERE???
   1920x1080     60.01
```

Pulling hair and running out of ideas how to fix this. Any pointers much appreciated.
Thanks!

**Notes:**

- I vaguely remember having this HDMI disconnect issues before but then the xrandr commands fixed it.
- Kindly note that I don't have nvidia graphics.

Answer (score 1):

```
PC: Have you tried turning it off and on again
Me: Yes
PC: Ok,  then I have no I idea what wrong and I will not work.
Me*(4 days later)*: Lets do that again, this time keep a monitor connected and turned on. 
PC: fine, I can work with that.
```

Apparently a restart with the external monitor attached solves the problem :)

I don't know the root cause of why this happened but will update this answer if I find out more.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my third display haven't been recognized on Ubuntu 18.04 with Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2).

The solution that worked for me was to change the Kernel to 4.15 when the laptop boots in the OS load manager when you start your PC.

Hope it will help others with the same issue.

Comment: @ravexina, I'm sorry, just wanted to help people that have same issue.

Comment: No problem... ;)

Comment: @Ravexina kindly point to the duplicate. I have seen similar questions but not the same cases with same troubleshooting results.

Comment: @user2984127 The "duplicate" in my comment are actually duplicate answers and not necessary exact questions like yours :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I've installed the missing firmwares with `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git` and copy the missing files to `/lib/firmware/amdgpu`.

Additionally, the open source driver amdgpu only works dual monitors when I've added the kernel parameter `amdgpu.dc=0` in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT grub configuration (/etc/default/grub).

Don't forget to execute `sudo update-grub` after all.