# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS unable to detect second monitor

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, displayport

I have a desktop computer running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with the following hardware:

- 11th Gen Intel i5-11400
- H510I PRO WIFI MSI motherboard
- no graphics card

The motherboard has a DisplayPort and HDMI port. When I plug a monitor into either of the ports, the monitor works. However, when I plug my second monitor, only the monitor that is plugged into the HDMI port works.

Here is the output from `sudo lspci -v`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 4c8b (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
DeviceName: Onboard - Video
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 7d16
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
```

and from `sudo lshw -c video`:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

and from `xrandr --verbose`:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0x529) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
Identifier: 0x528
Timestamp:  943886
Subpixel:   unknown
Clones:    
CRTC:       0
CRTCs:      0
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
non-desktop: 0 
    supported: 0, 1
1920x1080 (0x529) 159.667MHz *current
    h: width  1920 start    0 end    0 total 1920 skew    0 clock  83.16KHz
    v: height 1080 start    0 end    0 total 1080           clock  77.00Hz
```

I have tried the following:

- installing `mesa-utils`
- looking through various pages on the forums including [HDMI not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121132/hdmi-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04) (but my problem appears to be different as I am not able to see " disconnected" in my xrandr output)
- Searching for the correct drivers on Intel and MSI website

It seems that my problem is due to a lack of the correct drivers for graphics? Would updating to the latest Linux kernel help?

Pretty lost as I am fairly new to Linux and would greatly appreciate any help on what else I can do to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome. You have 1 monitor plugged into HDMI and the 2 nd is plugged into DVI?

Comment: Hi, the motherboard has 2 video ports, HDMI and DisplayPort. So I have monitors plugged in to both ports.

Comment: Many video chip sets can not support 2 digital  connections at once.

Comment: I tried installing Windows and both displays worked with no issues.