# Ubuntu 22.04 stopped detecting monitor

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, 22.04

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo Think Pad. It was detecting till yesterday but after I connected a Windows laptop (another laptop) to the monitor, my laptop stopped detecting the monitor. I tried various threads but it doesn't work. I am using HDMI to mini display port connection.

Output for lspci | grep VGA

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: Okay. I made progress after 10 hours of troubleshooting. Now my laptop detects a monitor but it says no signal. I used this thread: https://askubuntu.com/a/1121139/1450041 and upgraded intel drivers.